# Unable to extract password protect .rar file

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, nautilus

```
My filename: MyRarFileName.rar
Password: 123
```

Code  I am using to extract password protected file.

```
unrar x  MyRarFileName.rar -p123
```

I am unable to extract the given rar file as it is password protect. I am using the upper code to extract the file but it is showing nothing more than:

```
unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers
Extracting from /home/codie/Projects/FivBot/MyRarFileName.rar
All OK
```

And I am not getting my files.

Comment: Are you asking us to help you pirate software?

Comment: How can you say that?

Comment: Where are you looking for you files?

Comment: We can see your [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1288507/revisions). Your file name has the pirate site listed in it. If you get your file from the *actual* software authors, it doesn't come as a password protected .rar file.